# How to call a procedure or function when we are not aware of the parameters?

Tags: delphi, function, dll, procedure

My application has to provide the ability of calling different functions and procedures from external DLLs. So we don't know parameters' count and their types. What should I do to do this?

Let me explain it more. My application is a RAD tool and it has its own scripting and syntax... I want to let users to use *ANY* dll file and call any function or procedure they want. I can't use the simple method of calling dll (`LoadLibrary` and then `GetProcAddress`) because I don't know what type the `GetProcAddress` refers to ( `var Proc:procedure (A:??;B:??;...)` ).

Comment: You could start by finding out the parameter count and types.

Comment: +1 Now that it isn't a "stupid" question anymore! ;)

Comment: I think you need to call the function entirely manually. To do this, you first need its address, but here you can use `GetProcAddress`. I will investigate the details.

Comment: Thanks to Andreas,David and Warren! All of the answers are correct and I'm confused which one I should mark as accepted! Let me decide after following each solution. ;)

Comment: @Javid Is it too late to contemplate embedding Python (or perhaps Lua) in your app rather than writing yet another script language. If you do it well, you can reap incredible benefits for a small effort.

Comment: Some advice: If you are like me, that is, to a large extent, you program because you enjoy it, because it is a form of *art*, and because you like to learn, then I think you should follow me example. For one, I am pretty sure that I could extend my code to work with all common calling conventions and function signatures with only a couple of days of work. And the result wouldn't be buggy or bad in any way. But if you program as a profession, that is, if your manager has told you to write some code to some customer, then all that matters is that the end-result is as good as required and that...

Comment: ...you complete the task as quickly as possible (time is money to your company). In addition, if you write a bug, then the customer (and your manager) won't be happy with you! In such a case, you probably should go with David's suggestion and simply use an existing library.

Comment: (I wrote my first syntax-highlighting text editor from scratch when I was 14 years old. I never thought I'd manage that, but ever since, I have learned not to overestimate the height of mountains. Most often they aren't as high as some people say they are.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple example that works on my machine, but I am not an expert on the subject.

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  hmod: HMODULE;
  paddr: pointer;         
  c1, c2, ret: cardinal;
begin
  c1 := 400; //frequency
  c2 := 2000; // duration

  hmod := LoadLibrary('kernel32'); // Of course, the name of the DLL is taken from the script
  if hmod <> 0 then
    try
      paddr := GetProcAddress(hmod, 'Beep'); // ...as is the name of the exported function
      if paddr <> nil then
      begin
        // The script is told that this function requires two cardinals as
        // arguments. Let's call them c1 and c2. We will assume stdcall
        // calling convention. We will assume a 32-bit return value; this
        // we will store in ret.
        asm
          push c2
          push c1
          call [paddr]
          mov ret, eax
        end;
      end;
    finally
      FreeLibrary(hmod);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: What you're providing here, while correct for the particular case of `Beep` is deceivingly over-simplified. In the real world one would need to deal with multiple calling conventions, with all the details of that (order of parameters on stack, registers used, who cleans up the stack, how results are returned).

Comment: @Cosmin: I know. That's why I wrote "We will assume stdcall calling convention." Still, there aren't too many calling conventions around, now, are there? I don't think the mountain is too high.

Comment: Delphi itself supports 5 calling conventions: register, pascal, cdecl, stdcall and safecall.

Comment: @cosmin only two of those are important for interop

Comment: I'm actually OK with assembly in the code (I don't know assembly much but it's ok for me to learn more about it) but I want to know the details about what differences do "stdcall","cdecl",etc. have when I'm calling a proc using asm.

Comment: @Javid: The Wikipedia article is quite good: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: @Javid: A great introduction to Delphi assembly is http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3766.asp. It has a 'chapter' on how to call external procedures/functions: http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3771.asp

Comment: `Javid: The Wikipedia article is quite good: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions` @Andreas: This is EXACTLY what I wanted!

Comment: Umm, I get `Invalid pointer operation` when I pass a pointer to my test C++ DLL. The C++ DLL recieves `PString` and I `push`ed a PString to the DLL. In the DLL, I changed the string with a new value with the same length. When I run the application, the value is changed but right after watching it changed, the IPO exception is raised.

Comment: Wow! Solved the problem...! @Andreas: I love to learn and write the codes on my own. I don't work for a company and the first version of this application is finished and available as a freeware. Currently I'm developing v2.0 and I want it to have nice features.

Answer (score 5):

I have a Delphi implementation in the scripting functionality of my ZGameEditor-project, search for "TExpExternalFuncCall.Execute" in the file below:

http://code.google.com/p/zgameeditor/source/browse/trunk/ZExpressions.pas

Tested and working under Windows (x86 and x64), Linux, Android (ARM) and OS X (x86). Handles stdcall and cdecl calling conventions.

But libFFI is probably way more general than my implementation so I would recommended that approach.

Comment: +1 for trying it in Pure Delphi.  You have more courage than I.

Comment: It's not completely "pure" since it uses a few assembly instructions (not sure it would be possible otherwise) but it works on x86 flavors of Linux and OS X using Freepascal too.

Comment: I mean without linking in libs.  Inline assembly is considered a "pure delphi" solution, since Delhi programmers practically invented the X86 instruction set. Didn't we? (Just kidding.)

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant like the PUREPASCAL define that is used to ifdef away assembly versions of various routines in System.pas. Sure I remember back in those early Turbo Pascal days when you had to declare inline assembly procedures using hex opcodes, things have improved greatly since then ;-)

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is known as a [Foreign Function Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) (FFI) and is not for the feint of heart.

I would not recommend that you attempt to develop your own FFI from scratch.  A very common choice of FFI is [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/).

The [Wikipedia page for libffi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libffi) lists the following projects as users of libffi:

> Python, Dalvik, F-Script, PyPy,
>   PyObjC, RubyCocoa, JRuby, Rubinius,
>   MacRuby, gcj, GNU Smalltalk, IcedTea,
>   Cycript, Pawn, Squeak, Java Native
>   Access, PLT Scheme, Embeddable
>   Common Lisp and Mozilla.

I personally make extensive use of libffi through a Python/ctypes interface to my Delphi DLL, although thankfully Python/ctypes wraps it up at quite a high level.

If I were setting off down the route you describe, I would strongly consider using libffi. If you take that route you'll have to do some work to be able to use it from Delphi since it is written in C/asm.

Comment: I have no idea if there is some serious flaw with my approach or not, but it *seems* to work very well...

Comment: @Andreas You can do it yourself of course, but standing on top of a well tested library will be better in the long run. What about different calling conventions? What about callbacks? What about marshalling more complex data types? And so on.

Comment: @Cosmin There's a library for everything! You know that!

Comment: @Cosmin Of course libffi is C rather than Delphi so it's going to take some interop to get it into a state to be used from Delphi code.

Comment: Starting with Delphi 2010 we can call arbitrary methods using RTTI; We essentially fill up an array with TValues and call a method, Delphi's code does the heavy lifting. I'd attempt faking some RTTI records and using that. It'd be fun!

Comment: But @Cosmin, if it's *fun* you are seeking, surely you should follow me and write some assembly?! ;)

Comment: @Andreas, that much *fun* might be dangerous.

Comment: If you want some serious fun, why not bypass ASM and code directly in binary? :P

Comment: @Ken, that's easier then you think. ASM is such a thin layer over the opcodes themselves, it really doesn't take much to go from "text" ASM to "binary" ASM.

Comment: @Cosmin, Yes, I know. "xor eax,eax" is essentially just an alias to "$31C0" (Then again, I believe it's specific to x86 cpu)... But relative jmp instruction must be real fun to write/maintain. I don't know much about ASM, just enough to understand what's going on... and write some (not so good) code. But I gained like... 90% of my ASM experience writting my 64 bits OS compatibility patch for the game "Civilization 2". Never did much ASM beside that. But it was a fun waste of time! ^_^

Comment: @Ken, `JMP +$10` would be `$EB $10`: that simple. Take a look at [Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253666.pdf).

Comment: @Cosmin, thing is, add any instruction during any maintenance inbetween... and you need to change every jmp that jump over the code you inserted... that's what I meant.  That being said, I believe we drifted WAY out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

As David H says, about FFI, it's hardly for the faint of heart.

However, you could use the source code, for example, to the Python ctypes extension modules for FFI, as a source of information on how libFFI (ctypes) is bound to a particular syntax (in this case python).  THe python source code, and its standard modules, are very readable.

Here is an example of using the libraries David mentions, in Python:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146847/

Since the sources for python (in C) are available, and since Python itself can be an extension in Delphi, you could use that to start with.   If you are up to writing your own complete dynamic language (as part of your RAD tool), then you are up to the challenge of FFI too.

I am personally not up for the challenge of inventing a complete, workable programming language and all its libraries, from scratch, so I prefer to hybridize what I know, together.  Native code in C or Delphi, and dynamic scripts in Python.   You can combine all three easily into a single application, as needed.

Comment: +1 to fix anonymous downvote. I personally see nothing wrong with the message: it shows a path to follow in order to see how `libFFI` works, and that's valuable. Now I'm not going to vouch there's absolutely nothing wrong with the answer, because I'm not an expert on the subject. If the downvoter really is an expert and saw the hidden flow, a comment would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I guess someone who passed through doesn't like ctypes/libffi!!

Comment: [I'm innocent! I never downvote without giving a comment starting with "-1".]